# DAX DISTINCTCOUNT Measure with AND condition on Slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

My Data is in a Table like this:

```
Question        |   Answer  |   User
-------------------------------------
Favorite Color  |   Red     |   User_1
Favorite Color  |   Red     |   User_2
Favorite Color  |   Green   |   User_3
Hair Color      |   Ginger  |   User_1
Hair Color      |   Brown   |   User_2
Hair Color      |   Brown   |   User_3
Hair Color      |   Brown   |   User_4
Eye Color       |   Blue    |   User_1
```

Using the Measure `Number = DISTINCTCOUNT(Strukturdaten[User])` I get the following Result:

```
Question        |   Answer  |   Number
---------------------------------------
Favorite Color  |   Red     |   2
Favorite Color  |   Green   |   1
Hair Color      |   Ginger  |   1
Hair Color      |   Brown   |   3
Eye Color       |   Blue    |   1
```

I use in my Report two Slicer. One for the Question and one for the Answer.
The Slicer filters with an **OR** condition depending on what I select. I need them to filter my data with an **AND** condition.
E.G.: Question in ('Favorite Color', 'Hair Color') and Answer in ('Red', 'Ginger')
With this Slicer-filtering I could `DISTINCTCOUNT` the Users with ginger hair and the favorite color red.

I have tried to build a Measur like described here: [https://radacad.com/slicer-with-and-condition-in-power-bi#:~:text=The%20default%20behaviour%20of%20the,%E2%80%9D%2C%20OR%20%E2%80%9CBlue%E2%80%9D](https://radacad.com/slicer-with-and-condition-in-power-bi#:%7E:text=The%20default%20behaviour%20of%20the,%E2%80%9D%2C%20OR%20%E2%80%9CBlue%E2%80%9D)

But I did not get the result that only **1** user was answering these two questions with the two answers selected.

Can anyone please help me build this Measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to convert the "OR" condition in the Slicer into an "AND" condition:

1. Create a Measure that counts distinct User

> ```
> Anz. Uniquer = DISTINCTCOUNT(Strukturdaten[User])
> ```

2. Create a Measure that checks the Slicer for the selected Values (In this case I decided to look at the Answers hierarchycal), does a little summarizing and grouping and calculates:

> ```
> Anzahl Frag (AND) = 
> VAR NumOfSelectedAnswers = COUNTROWS( VALUES( 'Strukturdaten'[Answer]) )
> VAR QuestionsAndAnswers = 
>     SUMMARIZE(Strukturdaten,'Strukturdaten'[Answer],'Strukturdaten'[User])
> VAR ANZ =
>     GROUPBY(
>         QuestionsAndAnswers,
>         Strukturdaten[Uniquer],
>         "@Answer", SUMX( CURRENTGROUP(), 1 )
>     )
> VAR ANZ_ALL =
>     FILTER(ANZ, [@Answer] = NumOfSelectedAnswers )
>
> RETURN CALCULATE(
>     [Anz. User],
>     ANZ_ALL
> )
> ```